# SSH into PS4 Operating System

Tags: macos, ssh, ps4

Is it possible to SSH into the PS4 operating system from my macOS using something like Filezilla or Transmit? Do I have to do some kind of jailbreak to do this or is it possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this would not be possible with a 'Vanilla' PS4.

You might have some luck with a Jailbreak, but I don't think you will get advice on that here due to the legal issues associated with that.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a jailbreak for this, for security reasons. SSH would basically allow an exploitation vector which Sony does not want. The system behind PS4 is actually FreeBSD-based, it's called Orbis OS.

So naturally, if you were to find a jailbreak working for your version, you could just use OpenSSH or DropBear or any other proprietary tool.

But certainly not without a jaibreak.